# having trouble getting malformed JSON cross-domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cross-domain, getjson

This is a very narrow scope of the code, but it is where the issue lies.

```
function getJSON(tabUrl){
  $.getJSON(tabUrl, function(data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

I am using jquery 1.3 because getJSON in 1.3 can handle malformed JSON.  The server I'm getting my json from uses the old parameter:'value' format.

Here is the perplexing issue.

If tabUrl is a cross-domain server and is valid JSON, it works fine.
If tabUrl is a local file and is either valid OR INVALID it works fine.
If tabUrl is a cross-domain and is invalid I get no errors in firebug but cannot manipulate the data.

I have no problem using jQuery 1.4 if there is a workaround someone can propose.

Comment: What does this malformed json look like?

Comment: valid json is in the format "parameter":"value"
the malformed is in the format parameter:'value'

Comment: What happens if you invoke data.toSource() ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Yahoo Pipes for this. I think it can fix your JSON and also return a JSONP for using cross-domain.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery 4.0 Breaking Changes list](http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards) shows that we are to make a text request and use eval() to evaluate the contents.